# Create a new Dataframe column containing a dictionary from two existing columns each containing lists

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe structure:

```
    Col1 Col2 Col3     Col4
    A    1    [1,2,3]  ['t','y','x']
    B    2    [2,5,6]  ['a','b','x']
    C    3    [2,3,4]  ['x','b','c']
    D    4    [4,6,7]  ['z','c','v']
```

I want to create a new column in the dataframe Col5 that will contain a dictionary using Col3 as the keys, and col4 as the value

```
Col5
{1:'t',2:'y',3:'x'}
{2:'a',5:'b',6:'x'}
```

Anyone know a good way of doing this other than iterating through each row? 
I am stuck as of right now.

thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us the code.

Comment: Can you provide the data in a more convenient format?

Comment: I would like to answer this but can you show the MCVE?

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('A'),
                    'col2':[['a','b','c','d']],
                    'col3':[1],
                    'col4':[[1,3,2,4]]})

df.head()
df['col5'] = df.apply(lambda row: dict(zip(row.col2, row.col4)), axis = 1) 
df.head()
```

This is how I have done it using the `zip` call over the elements of the row. Results

[image]

After the operation

[image]